# Calling REST WS from command line

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, command-line

I read that REST WS can be called from a command line. I know that they can be invoked from program code, but how directly from command line? I looked around the internet to know how this can be done, but didn't find any information on this. Can anyone please tell me how this can be done?  I have developed a rest ws app in grails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use curl from the commandline of any unix-like os.

For example, you can test some sample Facebook API like this:

curl https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

or to POST:

curl -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/resource.cgi

Answer (score 1):

You could use curl to ask a URL. I guess your web service can be queried using HTTP?
http://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to do that.